# ExtJs: Manually fire paste event in textfield when that textfield is focused

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a text field, which should contain the clipboard data, and the paste operation should be executed when that text field is clicked or focused, instead of pressing Ctrl+V key.

#### *EDITED*

I have managed to trigger the paste event but the clipboard data is null.

```
  fld.getEl().on('paste', me.pasteFromClipboard,fld);
  fld.getEl().on('click', function(evt,target){
            var ev=document.createEvent("KeyboardEvent");
            ev.initKeyboardEvent('paste',true,true,window,true,false,false,false,86,86);
            this.getEl().dom.dispatchEvent(ev);
        },fld);
```

The pasteFromClipboard is :

```
  pasteFromClipboard : function(evt,target){
      var pastedText = "";
      if (Ext.isIE) {
         pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
      }
      else if (Ext.isGecko) {
         pastedText = "";
      }
      else if (Ext.isOpera) {
         pastedText = evt.browserEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      }
      else if (Ext.isWebKit) {
        //WebKit based browsers. i.e: Chrome, Safari
         pastedText = evt.browserEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
      }
    evt.stopEvent();
    if(pastedText.indexOf('#') == 0){
        pastedText = pastedText.substr(1,pastedText.length);
        this.setValue(pastedText);  
    }
 }
```

How can i achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the object firing the event is different than the object listening for the event.

```
fld.on('paste', me.pasteFromClipboard,fld);
fld.on('click', function(evt,target){
    fld.fireEvent('paste'); // Trigger Paste Event.
},fld);
```

Now, both the firing and listening is tied to the `fld`